# Codility Triangle Question in Big O Notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

I've solved the Triangle question of Codility however I'm amateur in Big O Notation and I would like to ask how the solution has the time complexity of O(N * logN)?

Question: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/triangle/

Solution;

```
def solution(A):
    # if sorted
    # A[Q] + A[R] > A[P]
    # A[P] + A[R] > A[Q]
    # only needed to check
    # A[P] + A[Q] > A[R]
    A.sort()

    if (len(A) < 3):
        return 0
    
    for i in range(len(A)-2):
        if (A[i] > A[i+2] - A[i+1]):
            return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: `A.sort()` implicitly costs nlogn time. Your for loop costs O(n) time. nlogn > n and therefore dominates. Therefore your runtime is nlogn

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(A):
    # if sorted
    # A[Q] + A[R] > A[P]
    # A[P] + A[R] > A[Q]
    # only needed to check
    # A[P] + A[Q] > A[R]
    A.sort() // it takes O(N * logN)

    if (len(A) < 3):
        return 0
    // it takes O(N)
    for i in range(len(A)-2):
        if (A[i] > A[i+2] - A[i+1]):
            return 1
    return 0
```

It is either that it takes
O(N * logN) or O(N * logN) + O(N) to execute depending on whether the length of A is less than 3.

However by convention, the big O searches for value that is most significant in solving the problem for example if you have 3x^2 + x where x is any positive integer, the most significant value here is 3x^2 because when x is large the value of 3x^2 is far greater than x and this makes 3x^2 approximately close to 3x^2 + x.

In the case above O(N * logN) + O(N) is approximate to O(N * log(N)) since O(N * log(N)) is the most significant value here

Therefore it takes O(N * log(N))

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is benign here, and has a time complexity of O(N), as you'd expect.

However, the `A.sort()` call has an O(nlog(N)) time complexity. See the [Wikipedia entry for Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) for additional details.